# Surfingkeys browser extension has enabled, disabled, and lurk mode. How do I add a list of websites in surfingkeys to browse in the lurk mode?

Tags: web, browser, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-extension

Lurk mode is better than disabling suringkeys altogether. For example, Gmail website has list of abundant shortcuts, but still it's better to have surfingkeys' shortcuts as yourbackup. In lurkmode you have to press  to use surfingkeys and then press  to go back to lurkmode.

The readme file of github page says to add github in the surfing key lurkmode use the regex line bellow.

```
settings.lurkingPattern = /https:\/\/github\.com|.*confluence.*/i;
```

But that doesn't say what if I want to add many websites, around 10-20 maybe, to browse in lurk mode.The regex pattern in the line `/https:\/\/github\.com|.*confluence.*/i;` is not simple. For example if I add `/https:\/\/meet\.jit.si|.*confluence.*/i;` then it work for jitsi conference room. But if I add just `/https:\/\/github\.com.*` or `/https:\/\/github\.com.` then it may not work,(if I remember correctly). So probably the word `confluence` is not just a word but a keyword. IDK. I know how to add websites after websites in surfingkeys blocklist. But I want to add around 10-15 websites in surfingkeys lurk-mode list.

I have knowledge of basic regex in case that would be needed.
How can I do that?